# Extracting .zip in python using extractall

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the log folder in the data folder,  extract the compressed files in the log folder, and code them to save them in each folder

But i can't get rid of the compression
I think i'm reading the route correctly. . .

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import sys

try:
    args = sys.argv

    curdir = os.path.dirname(args[0])

    for directory in glob.glob(curdir + '/data/*/'):
        for path in glob.glob(directory + '*/*_SmmLogs.zip'):
            output_path = os.path.dirname(directory)

            if os.path.exists(output_path):
                continue

            print('Extract')
            with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as zfile:
                zfile.extractall(os.path.dirname(path))

        print('processing Chuck rep of ' + directory)
        print('reading smmlogs')
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    # input('error')
```

Terminal is 
processing Chuck rep of d:/Coding/zip haedong/data\20201104025058633\ reading smmlogs

Comment: If you print `directory + '*/*_SmmLogs.zip'` before you enter the inner loop, does it contain what you think? And what do you think this `if os.path.exists(output_path):` does? You get `output_path` with `output_path = os.path.dirname(directory)`. Since the path `directory` must exist, the output path will exist too and then you leave the loop with `continue`.

Comment: Main point: `os.path.exists(output_path)` is always true. So the next command will be 'continue'. So Python skips the following code in the loop and goes to the next element.